# angularjs expression in html <object> tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a scope like `$scope.doc_details` in my angularjs controller, and I want to use it to display a pdf file by using a  tag, like this:

```
<object data="{{doc_details.file_url}}" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

but it doesn't get loaded in the browser, in my chrome console, all I see is:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
http://localhost/%7B%7Bdoc_details.file_url%7D%7D
```

and when I just display it using `<span>{{doc_details.file_url}}</span>` it show the value.

Comment: I bet the object is evaluating the string before angular has a chance to replace it with the final data.

Comment: any workaround for this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem here is that the browser is seeing

```
<object data="{{doc_details.file_url}}" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

in the DOM before Angular compiles it, and obviously `{{doc_details.file_url}}` isn't a valid URL.

Directives can be your friend here.

Say we want to write:

```
<pdf src='doc_details.file_url'></pdf>
```

We can create a directive:

```
app.directive('pdf', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var url = scope.$eval(attrs.src);
            element.replaceWith('<object type="application/pdf" data="' + url + '"></object>');
        }
    };
});
```

This will defer the creation of the `object` element until we actually have the URL available to us from the scope (assuming it's already there - otherwise you'd want to `$watch` the `src` attribute on the scope until it became available).

[Here this is in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8KgA/).

Comment: Ran into this problem while using angular2. Any thoughts on how to use data-binding with <object> tag?

Comment: @satchmorun Finally this was the solution that worked for me. Indeed delaying the binding was the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

As of [AngularJS 1.1.4](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#114-quantum-manipulation-2013-04-03), you can use the `ng-attr-` prefix for the `data` attribute:

```html
<object ng-attr-data="{{doc_details.file_url}}" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

See the **`ngAttr` for binding to arbitrary attributes** section on [AngularJS: Interpolation and data-binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation).

Comment: This will not work with IE.  IE will not let you change the data attribute after it has been loaded.  You'll likely get a message box saying that access is denied.  You should load it via a directive instead to delay the binding.

Comment: is that still the case now? I can't seem to easily google "object html element angularjs" i get a bunch of results about passing software objects and not html element objects. I'm getting strange issues with my code. Any updated answer to this or a link to docs will help thanks :)

Comment: This is still the case with IE 11.

Comment: Noting that I've not had any success with this method on AngularJS 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you **satchmorun**, but if smb want change link without reloading page or modal you can use:

```
<pdf2 src="pdfUrl" height="heightForPDF"></pdf2>
```

And this directive:

```
app.directive('pdf2', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            src: "=",
            height: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            function update(url) {
                    element.html('<object data="' + url + '" type="application/pdf" width="100%" style="height: ' + scope.height + 'px">' +
                        'Для просмотра pdf:<br /> Для Internet Explorer установите <a target="_blank" href="http://get.adobe.com/reader/">Acrobat Reader</a><br />' +
                        'Для Chrome: <a target="_blank" href="https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213030?hl=ru">Проверьте настройки</a>' +
                        '</object>');
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
            scope.$watch('src', update);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Thank you **Jerry** from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29902376/9589516) and example of recompile a dynamically loaded directive.

p.s. "pdfUrl" and "heightForPDF" are variable in scope

Answer (score 0):

The browser tries to process the thing before AngularJS replaced the angulary expression with something the browser can work with, causing an error.

Adding an `ng-cloak` fixes the issue.