# Using AngularJS to generate PDF objects

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, pdf

I have an angular controller that fetches json from my server and dynamically shows them. The code is:

```
    <div ng-controller="myImgController">
      <div ng-repeat="img in imgs">
        <div ng-repeat="i in img">
          <img ng-src="{{i.id}}"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How can I replicate this in terms of dynamically generating  markup to show pdfs within the browser. The current code is:

```
    <div ng-controller="myNewPdfController">
      <div ng-repeat="pdf in pdfs">
        <div ng-repeat="p in pdf">
          <object ng-attr-data="{{p.id}}" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But i'm having problems as `ng-attr-data / ng-src` does not work in respects to changing the source of the pdf document. Just in case you were wondering, the `p.id` is the url of the pdf.

Can anyone suggest a solution? Theres a lot of stuff out but I thought i'd make a clear question for other people with the same problem.

Comment: I think you need to use a directive: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14903933/5335589

Comment: @Captain the directive jsfiddle doesnt work. Tried to implement it & nothing happens.

Comment: It works nice with `ng-attr-data`, i made a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/jgLX82JkZBIeGcRBUjMJ Have you tried to debug your data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Captains advice and went on to research Directives which then led on to be used to get a working solution. This involved multiple ng-repeats a request to my server and a directive used to generate the pdf objects. Let me know if you need some more insight. This is just a quick paragraph to show that the question is answered.