# Angularjs Code to display Pdf file in google chrome is not working but working for firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, pdf

Below code to display Pdf file in google chrome is not working but working in firefox.

HTML View

```
<div>
    <object ng-bind="pdfcontent" data="{{pdfcontent}}" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="800px">
    </object>
</div>
```

Angularjs Code

```
$http.get('/myurl/', {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
    .success(function (data) {
    var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    $scope.pdfcontent = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
});
```

I am getting below two errors

> firebug-lite.js:18877 Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the
>   'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only
>   accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was
>   'arraybuffer').(anonymous function) @ firebug-lite.js:18877
>
> jquery.js:2812 GET http://abc123.com/%7B%7Bpdfcontent%7D%7D 404 (Not
>   Found)

What is wrong in my code, how to to fix this, any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you problem is that the `data` attribute is binded once the object is been been rendered and therefore when your request response the `pdfcontent` isn't been binded

to solve this you can do two think

1. using a directive for this purpose like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903112/angularjs-expression-in-html-object-tag?answertab=votes#tab-top)
2. you can use an `if` statement like in the snippet below

```js
    $scope.downloaded = false
    $http.get('/myurl/', {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).success(function (data) {
            $scope.downloaded = true
            var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            $scope.pdfcontent = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
        });
```

```html
    <div ng-if="downloaded">
        <object ng-bind="pdfcontent" data="{{pdfcontent}}" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="800px">
        </object>
    </div>
```

Comment: is the url valid (you can open it in the browser)?

Comment: Yes Url is valid and correct , its working in firefox.